# Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `j`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-proptypes

I am getting this error:

index.js:1375 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` supplied to `j`.

```
in j (at HomePage.jsx:15)
in HomePage (created by Context.Consumer)
in Route (at App.jsx:17)
in App (at src/index.js:13)
in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
in BrowserRouter (at src/index.js:12)
```

I am using an external component in my app which i got from github which renders a video in the background. Here is the link for that. 
https://github.com/samAbeywickrama/reactjs-videobg

It's something related to proptypes but since its legacy and react suggests to use flo, I am not using type check at all.

```
import React from "react";
import {
Container,
Header,
Image,
Button,
Icon
} from "semantic-ui-react";
import VideoBg from 'reactjs-videobg';
import mp4 from '../../video/hack4.mp4';

const HomePage = ({history}) => {
 return (
  <div className='masthead'>
  <VideoBg loop={true}>
    <VideoBg.Source src={mp4} type='video/mp4' />
  </VideoBg>
    <Container text textAlign='center'>
      <Header as='h1' inverted>
        <Image
          size='massive'
          src='/assets/logo.png'
          alt='logo'
          style={{ marginBottom: 12 }}
        />
        CodeUp
      </Header>
      <Button onClick={() => history.push('/events')} size='huge' 
      inverted>
        Enter
        <Icon name='right arrow' inverted />
      </Button>
    </Container>
</div>
);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

children is a prop used within the VideoBg component to add the video source to it.

I've raised an issue on the lib repo to investigate further

Comment: add the link to the issue

Comment: Here is the issue link: https://github.com/samAbeywickrama/reactjs-videobg/issues/6

Answer (score -1):

This should be a comment but need more reputation for that...

I sometimes find it really tricky to debug react. There doesn't seem to be anything called j in your code

I do see one thing in this code - doesn't work, you needtext={true} `, see above`

jsx tag attributes are really jsx (Javascript) objects, so it can't deal with something like `text`. So you have to give it a hint that it is a boolean

This may or may not be the problem....